# Looking for the complete works of Euler and Gauss in full technical detail

Tags: reference-request, math-history, book-recommendation

Have either of these collections been compiled into book form? I'm big on context, recently read through Newton's *Principia* and want to continue going through the works of the bigger names of the 19th Century. A google search hasn't turned up much surprisingly - and I'd also like to get a recommendation from someone experienced in math so as to not end up with something popsci or biographical - looking specifically for the math.

Comment: Not book form, but have you checked out: http://eulerarchive.maa.org/ ?

Comment: Start here: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Analysis-Infinite-Book-I/dp/0387968245/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1476416047&sr=8-5&keywords=Leonard+Euler

Comment: The complete works of Euler would fill a room.

Comment: https://archive.org/search.php?query=gauss%20werke